Finding out if a series converges without solving linear recurrence relation
I am to study the convergence of the $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{a_k}{5^k}$, where $a_{k+2} = 7a_{k+1}-12a_k$, $a_1 = 7, a_2 = 25$.
I have found that the series converges and the value of the sum is $\frac{11}{2}$ by solving the recurrence relation. However, my question is: is it possible to determine the convergence of the series without solving linear recurrence relation?

Observe that for $k\geq 2$ \begin{align}S_k:&=\frac{a_{k+1}/5^{k+1}}{a_k/5^k}=\frac{7a_k-12a_{k-1}}{5a_k}\\&=\frac75-\frac{12}{25}\frac{a_{k-1}/5^{k-1}}{a_k/5^k}=\frac75-\frac{12}{25}\frac1{S_{k-1}}.\end{align}
It's now easy to prove by induction that $0\leq S_k\leq \frac45$ for all $k$: For the upper bound note $S_1=\frac 57<\frac 45$, and assuming the claim holds for $S_{k-1}$, we have by the above equation $$S_k=\frac75-\frac{12}{25}\frac1{S_{k-1}}\leq\frac75-\frac{12}{25}\frac54=\frac45.$$ To show that $S_k$ is positive, it suffices to prove $a_k>0$, which follows from $a_{k+1}\geq 3a_k$, which is another easy induction, with inductive step $$a_{k+1}=7a_k-12a_{k-1}\geq 7a_k-\frac{12}3a_k=3a_k.$$
Thus, by the ratio test for series, the series $\sum\frac{a_k}{5^k}$ converges.

I've upvoted this answer, as my answer essentially solves it instead of "checking" for convergence.

Your proof by induction holds if $S_n>0.$

@RyszardSzwarc That's a good point, I'll edit

By the way the downvote is not mine.

We can use the theory of generating functions. Let $A(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nz^n$, and note that the recurrence can equivalently be written
$$
a_n = 7a_{n-1} - 12a_{n-2}-7\delta_{n,1} +2\delta_{n,0} \quad (n\ge0)
$$
where $\delta$ is the kronecker delta and $a_n = 0$ for $n<0$. Multiply both sides by $z^n$ and sum on $n$ to get the equation
$$
A(z)(1-7z+12z^2)=-7z+2\implies A(z)=\frac{-7z+2}{(1-3z)(1-4z)}.
$$
If we regard $A(z)$ as a power series then it converges for $|z|<1/4$. Because $1/5$ is in the disc of convergence, it follows that
$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{a_k}{5^k}$ converges.

The recurrence equation can be written
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
a_{k+2} \\
a_{k+1}
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
7 & -12 \\
1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
a_{k+1} \\
a_{k}
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
The eigenvalues of the square matrix are easily found to be $3$ and $4$.
This implies that $a_k=O(4^k)$ so the terms of the series will be $O((\frac45)^k),$ and since $|\frac45|<1$ the series converges.

Without solving the recurrence, from the characteristic polynomial of the equation we can deduce that $a_k = A 3^k + B 4^k$ for some constants $A, B \in \mathbb{R}$. The convergence immediately follows.

Why the downvote?
